# How to create bookmarklet from file in Jekyll?

Tags: javascript, html, escaping, jekyll, liquid

I've got an old [project with a bookmarklet](https://gitlab.com/victor-engmark/YouTube-channel-web-feed-bookmarklet) which has some slightly technical instructions to convert a JavaScript file into a bookmarklet by basically creating a dummy bookmark and replacing the location field. I'd like to change this into a bookmarklet on my Jekyll-generated blog, so that users can simply drag and drop the link to the bookmark bar to install it.

One hard requirement is *keeping the JavaScript code in a separate file* (to be easily modified and linted), and, if at all possible, to not have to keep two versions of the file in sync. What I've tried so far is [this](https://gitlab.com/engmark/victor-engmark.gitlab.io/-/merge_requests/119/diffs?diff_id=531481883#f887ec79914062abfaf35086a6f84935d0e1442b_0_12):

```
[foo][1]

[1]:javascript:{% include foo.js %}
```

But this doesn't escape the JavaScript code, so the web page ends up being a mess of a link and a `<code>` block. I also tried `include foo.js | escape`, which seems to be a syntax error.

How can I include a file *and* escape it to be usable as a bookmarklet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the right thing, URL-encoding the contents of the JavaScript file with `%20` for spaces*:

```
[foo][1]
{% capture raw_bookmarklet %}{% include foo.js %}{% endcapture %}
[1]:javascript:{{ raw_bookmarklet | uri_escape }}
```

Resulting [code](https://gitlab.com/engmark/victor-engmark.gitlab.io/-/commit/800f8a9190fb0db3b3e41d4b1eecfecea4520b65) and [page](https://paperless.blog/youtube-channel-web-feed-bookmarklet).

*: `url_encode` replaces spaces with `+`, resulting in syntax errors.